# When to use "Filterer" vs "Filter"?

Tags: verbs

The Collins dictionary defines "filterer" as:

```
a thing which filters or acts as a filter
```

Does anyone have example of where you would prefer "filterer" to "filter"?

Comment: No, in fact I have never heard that word. Although I have installed hundreds of filters. Try using The Cambridge it has Filter but  not Filterer. Sorry if this is no help.

Comment: It was a friend who used the word, and my initial reaction was to doubt it's existence. You're right Cambridge doesn't have it but most other online dictionaries do seems to include it.

Comment: I would suggest that a filterer is something which uses a filter to do its job. Because a filterer acts as a filter (because that's what is doing the job), using the word is largely redundant. But there may a use case where the internal component is important as well as the overall filtration apparatus.

Comment: Google Ngrams would be a reasonable place to begin research. The results I've found show specialised scientific/technical usages, with a single exception where the reasonable sense 'one who uses a filter/filtering device' must be inferred (as Andrew suggests).

Comment: @ Andrew Leach "But there may a use case where the internal component is important as well as the overall filtration apparatus"  .The machine/device that does the filtering is called a filter but the internal device is also called a filter, (filter cloth, filter paper, filter membrane, bag filter, box filter, etc).

Comment: *I am a filterer. It's my job to filter out bad information.*

Comment: I think that usage makes a lot of sense @JasonBassford

Answer (score 1):

I had suggested the following context in a comment under the question:

> I am a filterer. It's my job to filter out bad information.

My thinking was *filterer* should distinguish itself from *filter* by designating somebody's role—rather than describing an object.

Although I realize that jars with the Collins definition of *a thing,* I thought I'd take a look at Merriam-Webster's definition of [*filterer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filterer)—and I discovered something very interesting:

> : a worker who tends a filtration process in any of various capacities (as by operating a filter press)
>
> — called also *filterman*

Here is its definition of [*filterman*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filterman):

> **1** : FILTERER
> **2** : DECKER MAN

And here is its definition of [*decker man*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decker%20man):

> : a paper-mill worker who operates a wet machine
>
> — called also *filterman*

---

I should mention, however, that [Lexico (Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/filterer) gives essentially the same definition as Collins:

> Something which filters, or which acts as a filter.

Additionally, it provides no definition of either *filterman* or *decker man*.